# Ghostdoc 'document this' shortcut not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ghostdoc

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition V15.8.4 and the latest Ghostdoc version available in the Marketplace (Build 2018.1.18330).

Since the last update, Ghostdoc no longer recognizes any assigned shortcut. Whenever any shortcut other than Ctrl+Shift+D is assigned, on 'document this' Ghostdoc says 'Ghostdoc noticed that you don't have a shortcut associated with Document This. Do you want to re-assign the Ctrl+Shift+D shortcut?'.

It doesn't matter how the shortcut is assigned (Tools => Options => Keyboard or Ghostdoc re-assign shortcut). The error also pops up if I use the menu rather than the shortcut to document something.

The shortcuts tried are not used anywhere else, and I also get the error if I assign one of the shortcuts suggested by Ghostdoc.

If I uninstall Ghostdoc for VS 2017, there still remains Ghostdoc Community which has no option to uninstall. Disabling it makes no difference and trying to document something only using this edition, it always says 'action cannot be performed, VS still loading the project', even after the project is clearly fully loaded.

If I assign a shortcut and cancel the '...re-assign the Ctrl+Shift+D shortcut?' popup, commenting with the new shortcut actually works.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how it can be fixed. If not, is it possible to manually add the shortcut somewhere, e.g. the settings file?

Answer (score 0):

Serge B. here, I'm with SubMain (the GhostDoc company).

From what you are describing you may have the MSI version of GhostDoc installed. Please uninstall it in Progmas and Features.

This KB article describes different symptom but the solution is the same - https://support.submain.com/kb/a53/troubleshooting-vsix-installation-issues.aspx

My advice is to uninstall both MSI (Programs and Files) and VSIX (VS Extensions and Updates), then install the latest GhostDoc Community we recently released. It includes a fix with the shortcut assignment which may be related to the issue you are experiencing.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi sergeb. I just re-installed my computer, installed the `GhostDoc.v2021.2.21150.VS2017-VS2019.Extension.vsix`, but I still don't have the shortcut working. In VS options, I see that the ghostdoc "Document this" is properly bound to ctrl+shift+d, but it doesn't work. If I do it by mouse(right click, document this) it works. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @J4N this may have to do with a conflict inside VS or by another extension. Please email us at support at submain dot com and we will help you troubleshoot the issue. Thanks!